# Update polygon layer with summarized areas from other polygon layer

Tags: qgis, sql

I use QGIS 3.2.3. I have two polygon layers "municipalities" and "landuse".

I want to update *municipalities* with the summarized area off *landusepolygons* within every municipality. *landuse polygons* do, in some cases, cross the borders of *municipalities*, in those cases I want only the intersection area in the calculation.

I can't find a way to do it with the build ind tools in QGIS. I have installed the plugin "refFunctions", but I can't figure out how to set it up.

A virtual layer with some sql would do it, I think. I can calculate the total area, but how do I get an summarized area for the *landusepolygons* in every municipality?

Answer (score 2):

Using `refFunctions` plugin, this is a workflow I would suggest.

(0) Sample Data: To simplify I prepared only one municipalities.

[image]

(1) Open attribute table of `landuse` layer. Calculate intersecting area of each landuse polygon, and summarize (aggregate) them to new field `sum_area`.

The expression is:

```
 sum(area(intersection(geom_from_wkt(geomintersects('municipalities', '$geometry')), $geometry)), group_by:= "type")
```

[image]

(2) Open the attribute table of `municipalities` and extract data from `landuse` layer.

The expression is `attribute(get_feature('landuse', 'type', 'oat'), 'sum_area')` and you will need to repeat this for each landuse type (e.g. 'oat', 'vegie', 'wheat',...)

[image]

Caveat: As you can see, this workflow covers one municipalities polygon only. You will have multiple polygons, so you might need either (aa) to break them into single polygon and repeat above process one by one; or (bb) to automatically loop through all municipalities polygons by model builder.

Would not be easy, but hope this helps to some extent...

Answer (score 1):

Well..

I endet up with a more manuel solution... I clippet my landuselayer. Savet it as a new table, and calculated the areas of each part. Then, by using refFunctions, i summarized the areas in my municipalities table.

It works for now, but it was not the "smart solution" I was hoping for...